# How to write MongoDB queries for User-Visit-WebPage behavior?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I want to write queries for users visiting Web Page in MongoDB. The User and Website object looks like this：

```
User
{
   Integer _id,
   String Name,
   ....
}

WebPage:
{
  Integer _id,
  String URL,
  Integer CountOfVisitor,
  Visitors:
  [
    {
      Integer Visitor_id, //this field is consistent with the User._id field
      Integer VisitTime
    }
    ....
  ]
}
```

A sample of Web Page collection is

```
   {
      {1, "http://stackoverflow.com/",10000, [{1,1},{2,13},{5,32}....}],
      {2, "http://codeproject.com/",5000, [{2,6},{4,23},{12,32}....}],
      .....
   }
```

The scenario is that when a new user visits a web page, a new object will be inserted into the Vistors array of the correspond WebPage object and the CountOfVisitor field will be incremented by 1. When a old user visit a web page, the VisitTime field of the correspond object in the Visitors array will be incremented by 1 (the initial value is 1) and the CountOfVisitor field doesn't change.
So how to write one or more queries to implement such behavior?

Comment: Can you provide a sample document ?

Comment: Sure, `{1, "http://stackoverflow.com/",10000, {{2,1},{1,13},{5,32}....}}`

Comment: This is really not a good idea. Remember that there is a 16MB limit for MongoDB documents. You will exceed that limit after about a million visitors, which is nothing for a popular website.

Comment: your Json won't have key ? I don't  think this is a correct document

Comment: @ Philipp, I agree with you. But I just consider low visit load now.

Comment: @ Rohit Jain, you mean identifier? for the WebPage object it's the _id field.

Comment: Does your json look like this {"_id":1, "URL":"http://stackoverflow.com/","CountOfVisitor":10000, "Visitors":[{"Visitor_id":1,"VisitTime":1},{"Visitor_id":2,"VisitTime":13},{"Visitor_id":5,"VisitTime":32}]} ?